# UITextField that handles multiple languages

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, internationalization, uitextfield, multilingual

My app has a `UITextField`, which only works with one language -- English -- but I want it to use multiple languages. How can I do this? Is there a specific option or a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open on device/simulator **Settings** application **->General->International->Language**. Select here your language and keyboard will have required letters.

At current moment iOS can work only with 1 active language, to switch it you need to visit Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

The user can type into a UITextField using any language - they set the keyboard/language preferences for their device in themselves, in the global settings.